# What's the difference between blood value units 'mE/l', 'mU/l', 'mIU/l' and 'mEq/l'?

Tags: hematology, measurement

Wikipedia suggests 'mE/l' is the dutch or german translation (using 'eenheid'/'einheit' for 'unit') for '[mU/l](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_unit)', which can also be written as 'mIU/l'.

The article mentions `The IU should not be confused with the enzyme unit, also known as the International unit of enzyme activity and abbreviated as U.`. Is it safe to assume that in case of the unit 'mU/l' one never means the enzyme unit? I figure this is because the enzyme unit specifies a rate of conversion, which is not a blood value and would be meaningless to specify 'per liter'.

I have also encountered '[mEq/l](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_%28chemistry%29)', of which I am pretty sure it is different from 'mU/l', going by the wikipedia article.

Comment: did you read wiki article? there seems to be definitions on how units converted in mg. equivalents are essentially moles multiplied by charge of chemical. please read those pages and then articulate exact questions here

Comment: I was looking for confirmation that 'mE/l', 'mU/l' and 'mIU/l' are the same, but all different from 'mEq/l'. 'Is there a difference' is a yes/no question, which seems less appropriate to ask on stackexchange than a 'what's the difference' question. Since it's hard to google these units and they are easily confused I hope to establish a single reference here.